# Selecting variant data- Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column in the user table that is called "Metadata" and is type variant.
The JSON looks like this:

```
{
"title": "zzzzz",
"seniority": "zzzz",
"location": "Germany"
}
```

I am trying to select the seniority field but the query is not working:

```
select
    user_id,
    created_at,
    metadata: seniority as seniority
  from
    users
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks a lot in advance :)

Selecting the metadata informations

Comment: What do you mean by “is not working”? Does it return an error message (in which case what is that error), no data or the wring data? You probably shouldn’t have the space after the colon

Comment: I am getting this error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: ':seniority as seniority from users' at line 4"

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the value of a specific field from a JSON object stored in a variant column as text in Snowflake, you can use the [get_path](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_path.html) function and cast the result to text using the ::text operator:

```
select
    user_id,
    created_at,
    get_path(metadata, 'seniority')::text as seniority
from
    user
```

This will return the value of the seniority field in the metadata column as text for each row in the users table.

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much Michael for your quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using `metadata:seniority::text`:

```
select
  user_id,
  created_at,
  metadata:seniority::text as seniority
from users;
```

Output:

[image]